# Enabling horizontal scroll in UIWebview

Tags: javascript, objective-c

Is there any way to load a pdf document in a UIWebview so that it can
scroll horizontally instead vertically?
Is it possible?..
If so pls some one gimme me the way to do this..

I wanna pick the words in pdf as we can do in a webview and also I wanna
enable search for the word as we can do in a webview. So having an image and
loading it in a webview wont suit my requirements, I hope so. So I did load
pdf in a webview. Now my requirment is to load the same such that it could
scroll in a horizontal pattern.

Can anyone help me??????

Answer (score 0):

To scroll a scrollView you should simply use UIScrollView property contentSize.width
You can consider an UIScrollView as window with size scrollView.frame.size behind which is a rectangular with ability to move and with size scrollView.contentSize. Something like that :)

Comment: Ya. Ur saying is right if we can load a pdf horzontally in the webview which I couldnt do that. Please suggest me loading pdf in webview that it could scroll horizontally rather than vertically. \n\n I mean, I can set the scrollview's contentsize.width if I can load it to scroll horizontally